# Scroll view not working in linear layouts

Tags: android, android-scrollview

I have 3 parts in my layouts, Upper, middle and bottom. I want to show the middle layout as scroll view. In my code, scroll view is not showing.

Here is my code:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >
          <... ... ...   ..upper.....>
   <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" >

                <TextView

                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="4"
                    android:gravity="center"

                    />

            </LinearLayout>
         <... ... ...   ..Middle part.....>

               <ScrollView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="3.63">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="7"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp">
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="2"

                        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp">
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:paddingRight="10dp"
                            android:gravity="center"
                          />

                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="2"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp">
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1.5"
                             android:paddingRight="10dp"
                            android:gravity="right|center"/>
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1.5""
                            android:gravity="left|center"/>
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp">
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1.5"
                            android:paddingRight="10dp"
                            android:gravity="right|center"
                          />
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1.5"
                             android:gravity="left|center"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                           android:layout_marginBottom="3dp">
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1.5"
                             android:paddingRight="10dp"
                             android:textStyle="bold"

                      />
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                             android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1.5"
                            android:gravity="left|center" android:paddingRight="10dp"/>

                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                         android:layout_marginBottom="3dp">
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1.5"
                             android:paddingRight="10dp"
                              android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:gravity="right|center"/>
                        <EditText
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                             android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1.2"
                             android:paddingRight="10dp"
                                />
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="0.3"
                           android:gravity="center"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                   <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                           android:layout_marginBottom="3dp">
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1.5"
                             android:paddingRight="10dp"
                               android:textStyle="bold"
                                 android:gravity="right|center"/>

                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp">
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1.5"
                             android:paddingRight="10dp"
                          android:textStyle="bold"
                           android:gravity="right|center"/>

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                       android:layout_marginBottom="3dp">
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1.5"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:paddingRight="10dp"
                        android:gravity="right|center"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="0.3"
                           android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:gravity="center"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1.5"
                         android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">
                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

 <... ... ...   ..lower part.....>


          <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    >


                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="2"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:paddingRight="30dp"
                        android:drawablePadding="2dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="40dp"
                        >

                    </TextView>


                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You Should not give weights for linearLayouts which are created inside Scroll view, Then only the scroll will work.

Comment: you haven't defined weight sum anywhere. Directly giving weight is not proper approach

Answer (score 0):

**You should not give weightSum to ScrollView**, add ScrollView in LinearLayout and that's it

Try this solution, will solve your problem

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <TextView

                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:gravity="center" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="7"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"

                        android:layout_weight="2">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:hint="234"
                            android:paddingRight="10dp" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                        android:layout_weight="2">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1.5"
                            android:gravity="right|center"
                            android:hint="234"
                            android:paddingRight="10dp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1.5"
                            android:gravity="left|center"
                            android:paddingLeft="5dp" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1.5"
                            android:gravity="right|center"
                            android:hint="345"
                            android:paddingRight="10dp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1.5"
                            android:gravity="left|center"
                            android:paddingLeft="5dp" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1.5"
                            android:hint="345"
                            android:paddingRight="10dp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1.5"
                            android:gravity="left|center"
                            android:hint="345"
                            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                            android:paddingRight="10dp" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1.5"
                            android:gravity="right|center"
                            android:hint="345"
                            android:paddingRight="10dp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <EditText
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1.2"
                            android:paddingRight="10dp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="0.3"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:hint="345" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1.5"
                            android:gravity="right|center"
                            android:hint="345"
                            android:paddingRight="10dp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1.5"
                            android:gravity="right|center"
                            android:hint="345"

                            android:paddingRight="10dp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1.5"
                            android:gravity="right|center"
                            android:hint="345"
                            android:paddingRight="10dp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="0.3"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:hint="345"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1.5"
                        android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:drawablePadding="2dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingLeft="40dp"
                android:paddingRight="30dp">

            </TextView>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: tell me if facing any issue @user5826068

Answer (score 0):

You have to use ScrollView inside a LinearLayout:

Eg:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </ScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>
```